# angular2 routerLink does not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

**firstpage_server_side_load.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to myapp</title>
<base href="/temp/angular/" />
 <script src="/temp/angular/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/temp/angular/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/temp/angular/node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   
    <script src="/temp/angular/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/temp/angular/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/temp/angular/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/temp/angular/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/temp/angular/node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/temp/angular/node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="nav set-navigation-tab-nav navigation">
    <ul class="set-navigation-tab-nav">
       <li class="set-navigation-tab-container">
          <a [routerLink]="['home/home']">Home</a>
        </li>
       <li class="set-navigation-tab-container">
                <a [routerLink]="['user/register']">register</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script>

      System.config({
          baseURL: '/temp/angular/',
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        },

      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Utils} from './util/Utils';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS }    from 'angular2/http';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS }    from 'angular2/router';
import {myappComponent} from './myapp.component';
bootstrap(myappComponent,[HTTP_PROVIDERS,Utils,ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

**myapp.component.ts**

```
import {Directive,Component,ElementRef,Renderer} from 'angular2/core';
import {Home} from './home/component.home';
import {Route,RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {RegisterPageComponent} from './register-page/component.register.page';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/template/common/my.body.html',
 directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path:"/home/home",component:Home ,name:'Home',useAsDefault:true
    },
     {
        path:"user/register",component:RegisterPageComponent ,name:'User'
     }, 
])
export class myappComponent{ }
```

**Home.Component.ts**

```
import {Directive,Component,ElementRef,Renderer} from 'angular2/core';
import {Route,RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
 templateUrl:'./app/template/home/home.html',
 host:{
'(submit)':'onSubmit()'},
 directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})
export class Home{}
```

**RegisterPageComponent.Component.ts**

```
import {Directive,Component,ElementRef,Renderer} from 'angular2/core';
import {Route,RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'register',
 templateUrl:'./app/template/user/register.html',
 directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

export class RegisterPageComponent{}
```

**my.body.html**

```
<my-app>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <home>
    </home>
    <register>
    </register>
</my-app>
```

**Explanation** I am using XAMPP server, which load **firstpage_server_side_load.html** page on URL: **http://localhost/home/home**, Once page get loaded properly typescript get executed in script tag of html. All the required file loaded by this configuration.

**main.ts** execute configure web page for my applicatioon. All the steps working fine but once everything loaded then url of page get changed to **http://localhost/temp/angular/home/home**.

**Problem:** Now if I try to click on Either **Register** link or **Home** link both are not working. Even I don't find anything in console as well regarding these link like any error or message.
Please tell me how to make it work.
thanks

Comment: Your `routerLink` is in `index.html` It's not supposed to work. You need to add it in a template of a component.

Comment: It think  routerLink should be `[routerLink]="['/Home']"`

Comment: Thanks Gunter/Pankaj, It has to be in Component template and it's woking fine now. I also change it to [routerLink]="['/Home']".